# How to pass JSON body using GET method in android?

Tags: android, curl, okhttp, unirest

I have specific document, which requires GET method type and also pass a JSON body 
For example

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET -d '{"Date":"10-10-2017"}'
```

https://apibaseurl.com:8081/apibaseurl/methodname

Its working fine in **insomnia rest client**. I have also written code for same. Please suggest if any way to get proper response

```
HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.get("url")
.header("cookie", "PHPSESSID=7aikas61q77eskm3k1sfon5bq7")
.header("Authorization", "Basic authantication=")
.header("content-type", "application/json")
.body("{\"Date\":\"10-10-2017\"}")
.asString();
```

I have also write code using **okhttp** but not working.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{\"Date\":\"10-10-2017\"}");
Request request = new Request.Builder()
.url("url")
.get()
.addHeader("cookie", "PHPSESSID=7aikas61q77eskm3k1sfon5bq7")
.addHeader("authorization", "Basic YXBpcHVidXNlcjpzX20kVDJdXVNNbTY=")
.addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
.build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Comment: If you get any clues for this issue. please post an answer

Comment: Sure Nancy and also if you get then you can post